# python can't seem to get a list to return properly

Tags: python, list

```
   def best_wild_hand(hand):

    dictSuit = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14 }
    listofLists = []

    blackJoker = "?B"


    list1 = [x + "S" for x in dictSuit]
    index = len(hand)

    if blackJoker in hand:

        newHand = hand
        newHand.remove(blackJoker)
        for d in list1:
            newHand.insert(index +1, d)
            listofLists.append(newHand)
        return listofLists




    print best_wild_hand(['6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC', '5C', '?B'])
```

my out put should be in the format list of lists. My code seems to give me the every element in the list to newHand(which is also list). I only want one element inserted to newHand list and the newhand list appended to listofLists. I formatted it below

desired output list of lists

```
[['6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC', '5C', '2S']
 ['6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC', '5C', '3S']
 ['6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC', '5C', '4S']
 ['6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC', '5C', '5S']
 .
 .
 .
 ....................................'14S']]
```

Comment: Please check your indentation. It's hard to tell what's inside the `if blackjoker...` block and what's not.

Comment: Also, it seems you shouldn't iterate over `list1` ( the `for d in list1` loop) if you only want to append one card

Comment: hmm how else would i be able to add each card with out a loop?

Comment: You said "I only want one element inserted to newHand list" but now you don't? The problem isn't very clear to me, sorry.

Comment: @Junuxx i made the necessary indents

Comment: 1 element each from the list1 = [x + "S" for x in dictSuit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need even to append anything to the `hand` list in the `for loop`. It just creates unnecessary confusion. This seems to do everything you want.

```
def best_wild_hand(hand):
    dictSuit = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14}

    blackJoker = "?B"
    cards = [x + "S" for x in dictSuit]

    finalList = []
    if blackJoker in hand:
        hand.remove(blackJoker)
        for c in cards:
            finalList.append(hand + [c])
    return finalList
```

You can also do it *as a list comprehension* (and skip initializing `finalList` by returning the result immediately):

```
if blackJoker in hand:
    hand.remove(blackJoker)
    return [hand + [c] for c in cards]
```

Keep in mind that code like this `newHand = hand` where `hand` is a list does not create a copy of the original list. Therefore, it is a rather useless assignment in Python, as modifying `newHand` will also modify the original data referenced by `hand` since you are dealing with a mutable object (`list`).

***If you did not wish to modify the original list, you can copy it in the following way:***

```
import copy

# Now when you modify newHand (i.e appending or removing items) 
# the original hand list from the caller's frame will not be affected.
newHand = copy.copy(hand)

# You can alternatively copy the list using...
newHand = hand[:]

# However, if there are other mutable objects inside of `hand` you wished
# to copy, you'd have to use the `deepcopy` method of `copy`.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think After your code execution, the listofLists will be:

```
[newHand, newHand, newHand, ..., newHand]
```

But the newHand changed every time the loop processed, Finally, the listOfList will contains many the same newHand. You can write you loop block like this:

```
if blackJoker in hand:
    curHand = hand
    curHand.remove(blackJoker)
    for d in list1:
        newHand = curHand[:-1]
        newHand.insert(index +1, d)
        print newHand
        listofLists.append(newHand)
    return listofLists
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check your indentation - it's hard to understand what's inside the if, and the for. Here's my best guess as to what you're aiming for:

```
def best_wild_hand(hand):
    dictSuit = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14}
    result = []

    blackJoker = "?B"

    cardList = [x + "S" for x in dictSuit]
    index = len(hand)

    if blackJoker in hand:
        hand.remove(blackJoker)
        for card in cardList:
            result.append(hand + [card])
    return result
```

`append` can be used to put one element on the end of a python list, and is much cleaner than inserting an element at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
def best_wild_hand(hand):

    dictSuit = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14 }
    blackJoker = "?B"
    if blackJoker in hand:
        return [[x if x != blackJoker else str(i) + "S" for x in hand ] for i in range(2, 15)]


print best_wild_hand(['6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC', '5C', '?B'])
```